# Smallest Unattainable Product by Multiplying Digits in Decimal Notation

Tags: number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

$\ f(n)$ is a product of digits in the decimal notation of the number n.
What is the smallest $\ m \in \mathbb N $ for which the equation $\ f(n) = m$ is not solvable?

My approach was to calculate some values and try to spot a pattern:
$$\ f(10) = 0, f(11) = 1, f(12) = 2, f(13) = 3, f(14) = 4, ..., f(20) = 0, f(21) = 2,...$$ and so on. I noticed that the only outputs of prime numbers can be 2, 3, 7 which we get, for example, $\ f(17) = 7, f(117) = 7$, etc, therefore the answer could be 11 since it is the smallest of the primes that are left and since we are multiplying digits from 0 - 9 we could never get 11, because the only product possible is 1 * 11.

Is my reasoning correct and how can I put it into the more formal mathematical structure?

Also, is there such $\ m $ for which the equation $\ f(n) = m $ has finitely many solutions? I assume there isn't since we can always add another "1" digit to n and we get the same result, this could go on to infinity.

Comment: Your reasoning is good, but the wording is a bit vague.  And you are correct that, if there is one solution to $f(n)=m$, then there are infinitely many...for exactly the reason you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more rigorous version:

We claim that the answer is $11$.

For $m \leq 9$, we can see that $f(m)=m$. For 10, we have that $f(25)=10$. Thus, the lower bound for the answer is $11$. Now, we will prove that it is impossible to get $f(x)=11$.

Since $f(x)$ is the product of all digits, the only prime factors it can contain are the only prime factors among ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$. We can see that $11$ is prime, and so $11$ must be among the set as a prime factor.

However, since all elements in the set are less than $11$, this cannot be the case, and thus $f(x)=11$ cannot exist for any positive integer input $x$.

Comment: yeah ill go fix it